# Twitter Bootstrap - center navbar when responsive to two rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with a bunch of dropdowns.  When the navbar is on one row (full size screen), I got it to be centered.  When the screen size is small, I successfully made it collapse into a button, which is centered.  However, when the screen size is medium and the navbar is on two rows, neither row is centered.  How do I fix this?

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/grzt/US2sS/

You can resize the jsFiddle lower-right frame to see the different screen size results I mentioned above.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="text-align: center;">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-navbar-collapse" id="navigation-collapse-btn">
      <div id="navigation-collapse-text">Navigation</div>        
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </button>


            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation-navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="padding-left: 0;">Some Words <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Some Words <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Some Words <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Some Words <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Some Words <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Some Words <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Some Words <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        </ul>                   
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-nav {
  /*center navbar inner elements*/    
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

.navbar-toggle 
{
  /*center collapse button*/
  float:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep menu in center avoid using float. Check if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/US2sS/10/) helps you.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does give the desired result.  Could you explain why `<ul>` only applies to one row, while the individual `<li>`'s only apply to multiple rows?

Comment: I am not getting what exactly you are asking. What I did is I removed float for all the first li (using ">") below 768 width.

Comment: I had the same `float` and `display` code on the <ul> `navbar-nav`, but that only centers for one row.  And your `.navbar-nav>li` code only centers for multiple rows (I removed the `min:width` to test).  I was just wondering why.

Comment: You had centered the complete ul but not the inner li. It seems like one row was centered but it was not centered, it was occupying the complete space of ul and falling to the next line. Removing float of li and giving display inline-block made it centered.